# How to get results selected only by last date?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table KPI

```
KPIID   | CAMPAINID | CALCDATE   | KPIVALUE
--------+-----------+------------+---------
Metric1 | P-201     | 2018-12-04 | 10.00   
Metric1 | P-201     | 2018-12-05 | 11.50   
Metric1 | P-201     | 2018-12-06 | 12.25   
Metric2 | P-201     | 2018-12-04 | 10.15   
Metric1 | P-225     | 2018-12-04 | 13.75   
Metric1 | P-225     | 2018-12-07 | 15.05   
Metric2 | P-225     | 2018-12-04 | 20.00   
Metric2 | P-225     | 2018-12-07 | 25.00
```

KPI metrics are calculated for campains by dates.

I want to get result with such requrements:

1. table ordered by CAMPAINID and KPIID;
2. KPIVALUE foreach KPIID must be selected only with last CALCDATE.

Expected result:

```
CAMPAINID | KPIID   | KPIVALUE
----------+---------+---------
P-201     | Metric1 |  12.25  
P-201     | Metric2 |  10.15  
P-225     | Metric1 |  15.05  
P-225     | Metric2 |  25.00
```

Can you help to make the correct SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

This code fetches the rows that contain the maximum `CALCDATE` for each case of `CAMPAINID` and `KPIID`:

```
    SELECT 
      CAMPAINID, KPIID, KPIVALUE 
    FROM KPI k 
    WHERE 
      CALCDATE = (
        SELECT MAX(CALCDATE) FROM KPI WHERE CAMPAINID = k.CAMPAINID AND  KPIID = k.KPIID
      )
    ORDER BY CAMPAINID, KPIID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where window functions would often be used:

```
select campaignId, kpiid, kpivalue
from (select kpi.*,
             max(kpi.calcdate) over (partition by kpi.campaignId, kpi.kpiid) as max_calcdate
      from kpi
     ) k
where calcdate = max_calcdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select * from (select k.*,rank() over(partition by k.KPIID,k.CAMPAINID order by 
k.CALCDATE  desc)rank from KPI k)  where rank =1;
```

see it :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ca92/6/0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a more lengthy way, you can use Common table expressions.

```
;WITH MaxDatesCTE AS
(
  SELECT KPIID, 
         CAMPAINID,
         MAX(CALCDATE) AS MaxDate
  FROM KPI
  GROUP BY KPIID, CAMPAINID
)
SELECT K.CAMPAINID,
       K.KPIID,
       K.KPIVALUE
FROM MaxDatesCTE MC
  INNER JOIN KPI K ON MC.KPIID = K.KPIID
                   AND K.CAMPAINID = MC.CAMPAINID
                   AND K.CALCDATE = MC.MaxDate
ORDER BY K.CAMPAINID, K.KPIID ASC
```

Link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9bf6b00481820b5924ed7e5b9f8309b9